# Custom CSS is getting overridden by Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table. I am trying to center the table by applying custom CSS but the CSS is not getting applied to the table.

I have installed bootstrap via a gem:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

My custom CSS file (custom.css.scss):

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
table
{
 position:absolute; 
       top:50%;
       left:50%; 
}
```

and I am including  only `*= require custom` in `application.css`.

However, when I remove `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";` and `@import "bootstrap";` (i.e remove bootstrap) the table is being placed in the center.

Comment: I think both imports need to go into your `applicaiton.css`. Also, is the table rule getting overwritten if you add any kind of identifier to it (e.g. `#id` or `.class`)?

Comment: i tried placing it application .css too and i also tried with the CSS and yet it doesnt work :( however the same code is working with bootstrap in a non rails application

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this is to applying style attribute inside the table as the following:

```html
<table style="margin:0 auto 0 auto;" width="50%">
```

You should specify the width to work .
style attribute has the upper hand on bootstrap css.

Comment: i tried placing it application .css too and i also tried with the CSS and yet it doesnt work :( however the same code is working with bootstrap in a non rails application .